# SQL Group By Sum of Column Value Not Fixed Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table of data like this:

```
CommonURN GiftAidAmount GA_Status
14013084 2.00 45
14637494 20.00 45
14637496 1.00 45
14637508 5.00 45
14637520 10.00 45
14637525 19.00 45
14637562 10.00 45
14637586 12.00 45
14637590 3.00 45
14637649 5.00 45
```

I want to group my rows into blocks totalling £1000 or less, where the GA_Status value equals 45.

What I have so far is this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(CommonURN int,
GiftAidAmount money,
RunningSum money,
GroupID int);

WITH cte
(commonURN,giftAidAmount,running_sum)
AS
(SELECT
c.commonURN,
c.giftAidAmount,
        (select sum(c2.giftAidAmount)
        from dbo.[Campaign_Data] as c2 
        where 
            GA_Status = 45 and
            c2.commonURN <= c.commonURN)
FROM 
    [dbo].[Campaign_Data] c
WHERE GA_Status = 45)

INSERT INTO #Temp (CommonURN,GiftAidAmount,RunningSum,GroupID)
SELECT 
    commonURN,
    giftAidAmount, 
    running_sum,
    ceiling(running_sum/1000) as GroupID
FROM 
    cte 
ORDER BY
    commonURN

SELECT
    GroupID,
    COUNT(*) NumRows,
    SUM(GiftAidAmount) TotalGiftAid
FROM
    #Temp
GROUP BY GroupID
```

This works pretty well except that one of the groups in the result set is over £1000:

```
GroupID NumRows TotalGiftAid
1   100 999.83
2   107 999.57
3   91  990.82
4   114 1009.34
5   114 995.40
6   58  455.65
```

I don't understand why this is. Can anyone explain and help me fix it? Or suggest a better approach altogther?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but your sample data doesn't add up to anything near 1,000 ;)

Comment: No, there are 584 rows in the total set, I didn't think it would be a good idea to post them all. Is there a facility on SO to share larger amounts of sample data?

Comment: It's some kind of maths fail on my part, to do with the ceiling(running_sum/1000) as GroupID part. I think maybe I need to divide by 1001 or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a running value with single table update using a variable, and condition the variable to reset when the running value exceeds 1000. You can also update a GroupID based on this. Here is how I would do it. I insert a bunch of random amounts here anywhere from 5 to 30. The larger the amounts, the more likely you will run into a scenario where the running value is well below 1000, but the next value puts the running value over 1000:

```
-- insert test data
declare @Campaign_Data table
    (
    GiftAidAmount money,
    RunningValue money,
    GroupID int
    )
while (select count(*) from @Campaign_Data) < 2000
    begin
        insert into @Campaign_Data (GiftAidAmount)
            values (round(rand()*25,2)+5)
    end

-- update Running Value and GroupID; restart when amount exceeds 1000
declare @RunningValue money,
        @GroupID int        
set @RunningValue = 0
set @GroupID = 1
update @Campaign_Data
    set 
        @GroupID = GroupID = case when @RunningValue + GiftAidAmount > 1000
                                  then @GroupID + 1
                                  else @GroupID
                             end,
        @RunningValue = RunningValue = case when @RunningValue + GiftAidAmount > 1000
                                            then GiftAidAmount
                                            else @RunningValue + GiftAidAmount
                                       end

-- return values grouped by GroupID
select
    GroupID,
    count(GroupID) NumRows,
    sum(GiftAidAmount) TotalGiftAid
from @Campaign_Data
group by
    GroupID
order by
    GroupID
```

Comment: That is perfect. I've run that against my data and it does exactly what I was after. Plus, it runs in less than a second, as opposed to my query that was taking about 2 minutes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    GroupID,
    COUNT(*) NumRows,
    SUM(GiftAidAmount) TotalGiftAid
FROM
    #Temp
GROUP BY GroupID
HAVING SUM(GiftAidAmount) < 1000
```

Comment: Thanks, but this simply eliminates everything from group 4, which is the group with over £1K, the group with the running sum between £3k and £4k. I still need to output all my rows, just 'bucketed' into groups of £1k or less.